# Karate Can I set the name and location of the Cucumber Report

Tags: karate

I am aware of the following flag to generate a cucumber report:

```
 outputCucumberJson(true)
```

However, is there any way to specify the name and location of the cucumber report?

Comment: nope, you are welcome to contribute code. I really don't think this is important, you can always run a second process or script to move it wherever you want